# In JMeter, how can one user read each line of a CSV File successively?

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to create the following scenario in JMeter:

- There is 1 administrator who creates 'N' agents (Number of Threads/Users : 1)
- The credential of each agent is written on a seperate line in the CSV file.

How can I get the administrator to read each line of the text file successively?

Comment: Hi, here is link to needed element http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config. Also you can find example of usage in %JMETER_HOME%/bin/examples. And also you are welcome to provide us with youe Test Plan. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue using the following configuration:

[image]

[image]

[image]